# Prove that $ab$ is a cube of a positive integer.

Tags: integers

This is a question from ***Advanced Math Examination of Vietnam***:

**Let $a, b, c$ be the three positive integers such that $c+\frac{1}{b}=a+\frac{b}{a}$. Prove that $ab$ is a cube of a positive integer.**

First solution I thought about is form the hypothesis to a more similar one by move $\frac{1}{b}$ to the other side to make an inverse expression.

I have tried to form $a.b=c^{3}$ using the hypothesis $c+\frac{1}{b}=a+\frac{b}{a}$ but I can't find a good way to simplify the equation. It's too complicated.

Comment: add your work at solving problem

Comment: i think i don't understand much

Comment: Anyways, try to add all available related context: where is the problem from, what methods are allowed or will be clear to you, which of them have you tried, where did you stuck, etc. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note that

$$\frac{b}{a}-\frac{1}{b} \in \mathbb Z$$
and hence $ab|b^2-a$. This implies that $b|a$ and $a|b^2$.

This implies that there exists integers $d,e$ such that
$$a=bd \\
b=de \Rightarrow a=d^2e$$

**Simplification suggested by Will Jagy**

Therefore, $ab|b^2-a$ means $d^3e^2|d^2e(e-1)$ and hence $de|e-1$. This implies $e|e-1$ from where it follows that $e=1$.

Then: $ab=d^3$.

**Note** The simplification suggested by Will Jagy actualy proves the following much stronger claim: If $\frac{b}{a}-\frac{1}{b} \in \mathbb Z$ then $a=b^2$.

It is trivially to see that the converse is also true.

Comment: It's not immediately obvious that $ab|b^2-a$ $\implies$ $b|a$ and $a|b^2$. Can you shed a light why? Thanks.

Comment: @Alexey Burdin If $ab|b^2-a$ $\implies kab=b^2-a\implies a(kb+1)=b^2\implies a|b^2...$

Comment: @AlexeyBurdin I don't understand how you get $e=1$

Comment: @MermaidAine $ab|b^2-a$ implies $a|b^2-a$. Since $a|-a$ this means $a|b^2$. Same way $b|b^2-a$ and $b|b^2$ implies $b|a$/

Comment: @MermaidAine $$1=e(d^3e+1-cd)$$

Comment: NS, without dragging in the integer $c$ again, your relation $ab| b^2-a$ with $a=d^2 e$ and $b=de$ gives $d^3 e^2 | d^2 e (e-1),$ or $de|e-1.$

Comment: @WillJagy Nice observation, see the edit.

Comment: good.  I noticed the infinite family $a=b^2$ last night but was not sure those were all.

Comment: @WillJagy I think that the proof can be simplified a bit but it is probably not worth: $\frac{b}{a}-\frac{1}{b} \in \mathbb Z \Rightarrow b|a \Rightarrow a=bd \Rightarrow \frac{1}{d}-\frac{1}{b} \in \mathbb Z$. Now the difference is strictly between $-1$ and $1$.